# how to access history docker '<missing>' images

Tags: docker, docker-image

After making much changes in my code last night, I made a new image, and then I found something was wrong. While code rollback is much complex, I'd like to suggest using previous image for all end-user applications, instead of `latest` version in their docker-file.

The problem is that all history images are shown `<missing>`, the same as the one made two years ago. So, is it possible for I to identify the one, the last modification of which was 2-year ago, so that I can make a tag for all-end users?

Thanks.

```
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
c40bfd5de465        14 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["sh" "-c" "./docker-…   0B                  
<missing>           14 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 18080/tcp             0B                  
<missing>           14 hours ago        /bin/sh -c chmod a+x $AUTO_RUN_DIR/$VKERSERV…   6.74kB              
<missing>           14 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:1b1e438b24742cd0…   6.74kB              
<missing>           14 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:5d809f1661bd3bdb…   3.25kB              
<missing>           14 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:7208a6bafb3a6a01…   2.85kB              
<missing>           14 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:64bca67554c00d6c…   3.03kB              
<missing>           14 hours ago        /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /runtime/temp/vkmq/         0B                  
<missing>           14 hours ago        /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /root/vkds/vkredis-api/v…   0B                  
<missing>           14 hours ago        /bin/sh -c mkdir -p $WORK_PATH                  0B                  
<missing>           14 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV VKREDIS_APPNAME= VKRE…   0B                  
<missing>           14 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV INIT_MYSQL=init_mysql…   0B                  
<missing>           14 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV VKERSERVER_START=vkse…   0B                  
<missing>           14 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV AUTO_RUN_DIR=/docker-…   0B                  
<missing>           14 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV WORK_PATH=/usr/local/…   0B                  
<missing>           14 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:57dbba438276944df…   118MB               
<missing>           2 years ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:346d4cb58fff5e7b9…   2.02kB              
<missing>           3 years ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["mysqld"]               0B                  
<missing>           3 years ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 3306/tcp              0B                  
<missing>           3 years ago         /bin/sh -c chmod 777 /var/run/mysqld            0B                  
<missing>           3 years ago         /bin/sh -c mkdir /var/run/mysqld                0B                  
<missing>           3 years ago         /bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade awsebcli       11.4MB              
<missing>           3 years ago         /bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade awscli         38.2MB              
<missing>           3 years ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get -q -y install python-pip     97.5MB              
<missing>           3 years ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get -q -y install grunt          6.12MB              
<missing>           3 years ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get -q -y install npm            238MB               
<missing>           3 years ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get -q -y install mysql-server   359MB               
<missing>           3 years ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update                       10.2MB
```

Here is a sample component in th end-user's docker-compose.yml:

```
XXX-server:
    image: code.xxx.com.cn:4567/redis/redis-server:latest
    container_name: service-redis
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `docker history` output shows the steps that went into making up your image; it doesn't show past versions of the image.  If your image is built `FROM` some other image, the `docker history` output includes its steps too.  If I was going to guess from that history, you have a rather old base image (that includes some command-line tools, Node, and also a MySQL daemon), a somewhat newer intermediate image (which `COPY` some file in), and then your current Dockerfile is built `FROM` that.

On current Docker, if the "image" column says `<missing>`, you can't go back to that intermediate layer as an image.  (On very old versions of Docker this was often possible.)

It is pretty common to use Docker images to support the sort of rollback you're describing, though.  Don't label your images as `latest`; instead, use a date stamp or source-control commit ID as an image tag.

```yaml
image: code.xxx.com.cn:4567/redis/redis-server:20201113
```

Then if you discover today's build doesn't work, you can easily switch this back to yesterday's build.

You can also use [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) in the `docker-compose.yml` file to let the specific image version be passed in as an environment variable:

```yaml
image: code.xxx.com.cn:4567/redis/redis-server:${REDIS_TAG:-latest}
```

```sh
REDIS_TAG=20201113 docker-compose up -d
```